# Wrong virtualenv path installed with pip and macport

Tags: python, macos, pip, virtualenv, macports

I failed to install `virtualenv` on Mac OS 10.9 using `pip` and `macport`.

After installation with `pip install virtuanenv` I found the `virtualenv` was installed into `/opt/local/Library/Fraemworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin`.

But it should be in `/opt/local/bin`. How to fix it?

Comment: create a link 
`ln -s /opt/local/bin' /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip` ?

Comment: Yes but I want to install it to the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MacPorts cannot install an executable named `virtualenv` in `/opt/local/bin` because MacPorts supports multiple versions of Python and the different virtualenvs for the different Python versions would conflict on these files.

You can, however, install the `py27-virtualenv` port using `sudo port install py27-virtualenv`, which will give you `virtualenv-2.7` in `/opt/local/bin`. Additionally, installing the `py27-virtualenv` port will pull in the `virtualenv_select` port, which allows you to use MacPorts' select mechanism to choose your preferred version of virtualenv:

`sudo port select --set virtualenv virtualenv27` should then create a symlink `/opt/local/bin/virtualenv -> virtualenv-2.7`, which sounds like what you want.